# How to keep a feature in a pytorch model that isn't used for training

Tags: python, pytorch

I have several timeseries and I am trying to predict a particular feature on them. To achieve this I have built a seq2seq model with teacher forcing that takes 120 points and predicts 30 points (it's an encoder decoder architecture). I wanted to add **predictible** features that will be passed in the decoder in inference mode such as day number, month number etc.. And I also normalized my target feature.
Let's say my dataframe is like this :

```
index       target      d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6  d7
2015-03-04  0.075269    0   0   0   1   0   0   0
2015-03-05  0.126744    0   0   0   0   1   0   0  
2015-03-06  0.038530    0   0   0   0   0   1   0 
2015-03-07  0.000000    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

And let's say the predictible features are the dummies of the days of the week.
My training is going fine and well, and the model is *apparently* converging but I when I want to predict in order to see the results I have an obvious issue. Since the predictible features are passed in the decoder, I need to extrapolate them which is not complicated with the date but because of the conversion into tensors, I loose the index so i can't infer the features. Do you know if it is possible to index tensors in order to recover the date of the last row to extrapolate the features ?

**PS:** I can't use a trick such as finding the last day in our example because I have more than 100+ rows of dummies features, so I really need to find a way to keep the date but to exclude it from training

Thanks

Comment: I work on this stuff, and I don’t know what you mean. Your explanation of the question you’re facing left me very confused.

Comment: To be clearer, I just wanted a way to retrieve the date of a tensor (which is in index in my dataframe)